# OpenSSL Error messages: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: php, symfony, openssl, xampp, composer-php

I am new to PHP, I have a Symfony 2.5 project and the installed PHP version is 5.4.4.

I am using XAMPP for running the PHP project. When I am executing `composer install` it throws the below error

---

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   The
> "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be
> downloaded: SSL operation failed with cod      e 1. OpenSSL Error
> messages:   error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1
> alert protocol version   Failed to enable crypto   failed to open
> stream: operation failed

---

If you guys have faced this issue before, Could you please help me with this?

I have enabled the `openssl` extension in php.ini file

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

TIA.

Comment: what's your composer version?

Comment: It is - Composer version 2.2.17 2022-07-13 15:27:38

Comment: Why do you still use a horribly outdated PHP version? Support for PHP 5 has ended years ago!

Comment: Hi,  @NicoHaase It is actually a project requirement. We are planning to upgrade the project, but before that, we want to ensure that the app functionality is behaving correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved after upgrading the `PHP` version to `5.5.19`.